# Location not being updated on new geo fix in android emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I am trying to make it so a MapView zooms to a current location based on a GeoPoint.  I am setting the location using the geo fix command in telnet.  My problem is that when I first input a location using geo fix my code will correctly navigate to a location on the map.  If I try to set another location using geo fix however it does not update.  Here is the code to update:

```
public void updateLocation(Location loc) {
    p = new GeoPoint((int)(loc.getLongitude() * 1E6),(int)(loc.getLatitude() * 1E6));

    mc = mapView.getController();

    mc.animateTo(p);
}
```

and here is my code to call the update:

```
LocationListener onLocationChange=new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        updateLocation(location);
    }
```

etc...

I have the following in onResume():

```
    super.onResume();
    myLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 0, 200, onLocationChange);
```

The points I am trying to geo fix to are far enough apart to meet the minimum distance requirement.  Anyone have any ideas of what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

Call `mapView.invalidate();` *(see [View:invalidate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29))* or `mapView.postInvalidate();` *(see [View:postInvalidate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postInvalidate%28%29))*, depending on if it runs on UI thread or not, after

```
mc.animateTo(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your MapActivity implements LocationListener, then change

```
myLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 0, 200, onLocationChange);
```

to

```
myLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 0, 200, this);
```

'this' holds the location listener